# jasmine unit test failing for element.remove in postLink - angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

Unit test failing for a postLink method in directive. here's the code for a directive

```
myApp.directive("hasPermission", function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    'entry': '='
  },
  link: function postLink(scope, element) {
    if (scope.entry === 'removal') {
      element.remove();
    }
  }
};
```

});

here's the unit test I wrote

```
it('has-permission test', function() {
var element = angular.element('<div has-permission entry="not-removal">customer</div>');
  var element = compile(element)(scope);
  scope.$digest();
  expect(element.html()).toBe('customer');

  var element2 = angular.element('<div has-permission entry="removal">customer</div>');
  element2 = compile(element2)(scope);
  scope.$digest();
  expect(element2.html()).toBe('');
});
```

the second test(element2) where the link method should delete the element fails saying - Expected 'customer' to be ''

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a bit of a problem with your code , you are asking the entry to be removed  by saying

```
element.remove();
```

but then expecting this element to be blank

I have rewritten your code to pass it but I would suggest you closely look at your

my working plunk for this

https://plnkr.co/edit/YhIefYrIx4U0wrZZhyxl

BTW just scope to

```
 scope: { 
    entry:"@"
  },
```

from

```
 scope: { 
    entry:"="
  },
```

would solve having to break your test to make it pass . I have updated the plunk to the same

Comment: Ok, I understand that after removing the element I can't check if its empty. I tried using empty() method of jQuery still it doesn't work. I looked at your approach and I won't use it as you have simply written jQuery, javascript in your link function, though we have access to scope.entry.

Comment: you need the element to have gone out of the DOM , as in removed , i simply corrected your code to pass , by making the element empty. BTW i did not really use jquery (from outside ), i used the slim version of jquery Angular already comes with it

Comment: also just to point out , not 100% sure about this but $compile does not insert items into the page thats what you are trying to do . So when you write Remove and Empty its same result , but since you compiled it in a template  , not added to the dom and used same Variable to test  this test would really not achieve anything , and BTW in case of angular it uses jQlite and not exactly jquery https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Thanks for stating all the obvious facts, still your solution is not correct. You didn't find the issue with my implementation, all you did was writing some code (that's completely not acceptable) just to make the unit test pass. I did find the issue and have posted the answer.

Comment: no problem  .. you have solved your problem .. thats how it should always be cheers

Comment: BTW thanks to you .. i actually understood directives more thanks for that

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue with my code. Turns out there was a scope issue. When I pass the "removal" as a string in the HTML, it wasn't binding it to scope.entry field. So what I did was assigned the value to scope.entry and passed the variable to the template and $compile then did the rest.

```
it('has-permission test', function() {
scope.entry = 'not-removal';
var element = compile('<div has-permission="entry">customer</div>')(scope);
scope.$digest();
expect(element.html()).toBe('customer');

scope.entry = 'removal';
var element2 = compile('<div has-permission="entry">customer</div>')(scope);
scope.$digest();
expect(element2.OuterHtml).toBe(undefined);
```

});

Here's the plunker for this - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/HhzHENxohgwRNWCf?preview